# Apache redirection to sub domain

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, webserver

My website URL till now was as per this pattern https://www.xyz.com, from which i served both static and dynamic contents. https://www.xyz.com defaults to home page, https://www.xyz.com/static/index.html, and dynamic contents are served from https://www.xyz.com/dyna/login.jsp.

Recently I added an additional webserver and got sub domain registered from which I plan to serve static content through http URL scheme instead of https, and only serve dynamic pages from https URL. So, if user types https://www.xyz.com, should redirect to http://static.abc.com.

Webserver: Apache 2.x

My Queries are:

a. How to configure apache to redirect request on **https**://www.xyz.com to **http**://static.abc.com while ensuring that request to https://www.xyz.com/dyna/login.jsp does not get redirected?
Will this have any noticeable performance overhead?

b. If redirection from http to https and also launching http screen from https page lead to any security warning in this case? 
Note that I do not intend to submit any data from http to https and vice versa, it will be just URL redirection or links.

c. How to make the redirection cacheable?

Answer (score 0):

use .htaccess to define https://www.example.com/static/index.html as https://www.example.com/index.html

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain/static/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/index.html$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not answer my queries